Copy Folder Tree From The Database Table & Paste It Into The Destination Folder In Same Table Using C#
I have only one database, and only one table named WorkingDirectory.
I want to copy folder structure from source (RootFolder1) folder and paste it into destination (RootFolder2) folder in the same table using C#.

Below parameter passed from the UI side or swagger.
[
    {
        "copySourceFolderId": 1,
        "pasteDestinationFolderId": 5
    }
]

WorkingDirectory table structure:
|   Id  |   ParentId   |   Name          |
|   1   |   null       |   RootFolder1   |
|   2   |   1          |   SubFolder1    |
|   3   |   1          |   SubFolder2    |
|   4   |   2          |   SubSubFolder1 |
|   5   |   null       |   RootFolder2   |

Step 1: Get the Nth level of tree data structure from the table based on copySourceFolderId = 1.
Getting below result from the query and storing the result into "workingDirectoryList" object.
|   Id  |   ParentId   |   Name          |
|   1   |   null       |   RootFolder1   |
|   2   |   1          |   SubFolder1    |
|   3   |   1          |   SubFolder2    |
|   4   |   2          |   SubSubFolder1 |

with recursive subordinate as 
(
    select "Id" ,"Name" ,"ParentId" from ol."WorkingDirectory" w  where "Id" = 1  
    union 
    select wd2."Id" ,wd2."Name" ,wd2."ParentId" from ol."WorkingDirectory" wd2  
    inner join subordinate s on s."Id"= wd2."ParentId"
)
select s."Id",s."Name",s."ParentId"
from subordinate s
group by s."Id",s."Name",s."ParentId"
order by s."Id" asc


List<WorkingDirectoryModel> workingDirectoryList = new List<WorkingDirectoryModel>();

public class WorkingDirectoryModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

Step 2: One by one, add or insert records in the "WorkingDirectory" table from "workingDirectoryList" object using C#.
foreach (var item in workingDirectoryList)
{
    // What logic should written here?
}

Step 3: output of WorkingDirectory table after copy RootFolder1 and paste it into RootFolder2:
|   Id  |   ParentId   |   Name          |
|   1   |   null       |   RootFolder1   |
|   2   |   1          |   SubFolder1    |
|   3   |   1          |   SubFolder2    |
|   4   |   2          |   SubSubFolder1 |
|   5   |   null       |   RootFolder2   |
|   6   |   5          |   RootFolder1   |
|   7   |   6          |   SubFolder1    |
|   8   |   6          |   SubFolder2    |
|   9   |   7          |   SubSubFolder1 |


So, what is the question? While an example of what you want to do is good, is it not sufficient in itself.

Do you mean select from one database and insert into another database having same table structure ?

I mean, I have only one database and one table. Select or copy the Nth level of tree structure from the table based on "copySourceFolderId (Id/ParentId)" and paste or insert it into the same table with the newly generated ID.

If I understand your objective then this can be accomplished in a single query. A couple notes first:

Postgres allows DML within a CTE.
Postgres allows multiple CTEs to be generated.
DML operations are valid as the main query and can use any/all the generated CTEs.

With these then you get what you want with:
with recursive
     new_root(new_root_id) as
         (insert into WorkingDirectory(name) 
               values ('Root_folder2')
            returning (id) 
         )
    , old_parents(id,name,parentid) as     -- recursive part begins here
         (select * 
            from WorkingDirectory 
           where id = 1
          union all 
           select w.*
             from WorkingDirectory w
             join old_parents      op 
               on op.id = w.parentid
          ) 
insert into WorkingDirectory(name,parentid)
       select op.name, coalesce(op.parentid,0) + nr.new_root_id
         from old_parents   op
         cross join new_root nr;

The new_root CTE gets the new row with Root_Folder2 and returns its id. This is later used to generate the copied hierarchy revised ParentId. The old_parents just builds an image of the desired hierarchy to be copied. Finally the main query (Insert DML) generates the copy while recalculating the ParientId. (see demo here).

Thank you for the update. I want insert records in database from C# side using loop instead of directly insert using query. I want actual logic of loop which I mentioned STEP 2 in question.

As per my understanding, you need a parent-child relationship,
Please check this query I prepared in SQL.
DECLARE @WorkingDirectory TABLE
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1),
    Name NVARCHAR(MAX),
    ParentId INT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @WorkingDirectory
VALUES('RootFolder',NULL),
('SubFolder1',1),
('SubFolder2 ',1),
('SubSubFolder1 ',2),
('RootFolder2',NULL),
('RootFolder1 ',5),
('SubFolder1 ',6),
('SubFolder2 ',6),
('SubSubFolder1',7)


;with subordinate as 
(
    select Id ,Name ,ParentId from @WorkingDirectory w  where ParentId IS NULL 
    union all
    select wd2.Id ,wd2.Name ,wd2.ParentId from @WorkingDirectory wd2  
    inner join subordinate s on s.Id= wd2.ParentId
)
select s.Id,s.Name,s.ParentId
from subordinate s
order by s.Id asc

OutPut


Do you want to get data based on the query?
So you have to add a where condition in the CTE.
"copySourceFolderId": 1

--SQL QUERY
select s.Id,s.Name,s.ParentId
from subordinate s
WHERE (id = 1 OR ParentId=1)
order by s.Id asc


This is not valid SQL for PostgreSQL, please improve or remove the answer. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/index.html

@FrankHeikens I've added for SQL, not for PostgreSQL. Please check the second line  I Prepare a query for SQL

SQL is a language used by many databases, including PostgreSQL. Your piece of SQL just doesn't work on PostgreSQL, the database that has been mentioned in this topic. It might work in Oracle or DB2, but that won't help in this case.
